# Can't plot learning curve of keras model

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, neural-network, keras

It's my NN in keras. The model was compiled and trained. When I try to plot the learning curve of history, only empty window appears.

```
model = Sequential()
   model.add(Dense(64, input_dim=30,
                activity_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01)))
   model.add(BatchNormalization())
   model.add(LeakyReLU())

   model.add(Dropout(0.5))
   model.add(Dense(16,
                activity_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01)))
   model.add(BatchNormalization())
   model.add(LeakyReLU())
   model.add(Dense(2))
   model.add(Activation('softmax'))

   opt = Nadam(lr=0.001)

   reduce_lr = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_acc', factor=0.9,      patience=25, min_lr=0.000001, verbose=1)
   checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath="test.hdf5", verbose=1, save_best_only=False)
   model.compile(optimizer=opt, 
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

   history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, 
          nb_epoch = 1, 
          batch_size = 128, 
          verbose=1, 
          validation_data=(X_test, Y_test),
          callbacks=[reduce_lr, checkpointer],
          shuffle=True)

   plt.plot(history.history['acc'])
```

When I print history.history['acc'], it's just one number. Not a list.
I'd be happy, if you can help

Comment: Please make sure to have read and understood [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try increasing the number of epochs